# How to upload large file on server (up to 30 GB) even after request browser get closed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

As I have just started learning  web applications, I need help or suggestions on this.
1.I want to upload file on server that is around 30 GB in Size. 
2. If i select the file for upload, Uploading is in progress and suppose I closed the browser. still file should be uploaded on server. (like some service is running in background)
3. Is it possible to do in web..?

Answer (score 0):

Once the page or browser is closed, most (if not all) browsers will terminate the connection immediately. So right off the bat, the answer to your question is no, this is not possible. If you want to upload files in the background, you would need a native app to do this. For example OneDrive, Google Drive, MEGA and other file storage services require native apps for background uploads, and can't continue uploads in the browser once the browser or webpage is closed (If you could, you'd think they would have implemented that already!).

Additionally, [browsers have size limits for uploads](https://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pa98.htm), mostly for technical reasons, which you need to take into consideration. Currently only Chrome and Opera are able to handle HTTP uploads over 4GB.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using FTP for this. You could do this asynchronously with your app by putting the file transfer code within an asynchronous task (fire and forget)